# One button for CheckBox items in ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i put only one button for ChceckBox?
here is what i get:
[enter image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72QiW.png)

As you can see i have 10 button for each checkbox value but i need group them by "week" "Day" and in this case put only one for each of them. That "day weak" label come from sql and is dynamic value.

Here is code:

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PS_TestConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Prize] ">

    <ItemTemplate>             
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Prize") %>' OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged1" AutoPostBack="True" />
                 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /><br /> <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Receive the prize"  Visible="True" CommandName="foo" /></ItemTemplate>
```

I need this witch CheckBox in itemtemplate becouse i have to put image in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding a new GridView to ItemTemplate